# Weird behaviour of text view ellipsize

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to show textview with ... (3 dots) at the end if it is longer than certain width.  I have the follow:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxWidth="160dp"
            android:text="Style asd sad adas cvfvd dff dzxczx zc xcc x c"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

The problem that depending on the text length the position of the dots and how much is displayed changes!

For example
if text is:"Style asd sad adas"  then the display is

[image]

But if it is: "Style asd sad adas cvfvd df" then the display is

[image]

And if it is :"Style asd sad adas cvfvd dff dzxczx zc xcc x c" then display is

[image]

You can see the longer the text is the less is displayed (while background is reaching the max length). Why is this? How can I make it so that it is always the same text shown no matter how long it is (after certain threshold).

Thank you

Comment: Can share your whole layout file with question

Comment: The layout is very big? Is there something specific interested in? Like parents layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have `android:maxLines="1"`. Inorder to support bigger text maxlines should be increased. If maxlines is set as 1, the textview cannot jump to next line even if the text is big

It will give better results if  `android:maxWidth="160dp"` is removed

**OR**

Get rid of `android:maxLines` and use `android:singleLine="true"`, see below

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxWidth="160dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Style asd sad adas cvfvd dff dzxczx zc xcc x c"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: But maxline set it to 1 line (which what I want) ,right? It shouldn't be jumping to next line as there is still alot of space left in in one line. Isn't singleLine deprecated anyways?

Comment: have you checked second solution using `android:singleLine="true"` ? and removing `android:maxLines`

Comment: Yes and it works perfectly. I will accept it. But singleLine is deprecated and LINT is warning me. What would be the alternative? I thought maxLines =1 is the same as singleLine

Comment: try checking if there is lint warning when it is set programatically, `textView.setSingleLine(true);`

Comment: It is not deprecated in code but in xml. The problem all of stackoverflow tells you to avoid single line and use maxLine instead